# order by ASC|DESC in returning JSON object value - MySQL query

Tags: sql, mysql, json

I have simple table as shown below,

| datetime | Rupee | Pound |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-02-16 | 80% | 70% |
| 2019-02-17 | 30% | 60% |
| 2019-02-18 | 67% | 89% |

And MySQL query looks like below,

```
SELECT json_arrayagg(obj)
FROM (
    SELECT json_object(
                      'currency', 'rupee',
                      'data', json_arrayagg(json_array(datetime, rupee))
                      ) AS obj
    FROM currency
    UNION ALL
    SELECT json_object(
                      'currency', 'pound',
                      'data', json_arrayagg(json_array(datetime, pound))
                      )
    FROM currency
   ) x;
```

Result

```
[{"currency": "rupee", "data": [["2019-02-16", "80%"], ["2019-02-17", "30%"], ["2019-02-18", "67%"]]},
 {"currency": "pound", "data": [["2019-02-16", "70%"], ["2019-02-17", "60%"], ["2019-02-18", "89%"]]}]
```

The result is good with no problem.

The thing I want is `data` to come in `ASC|DESC` order on Rupee or Pound column.

The expected result would look like below,

```
[{"currency": "Rupee", "data": [["2019-02-17", "30%"], ["2019-02-18", "67%"], ["2019-02-16", "80%"]]},
 {"currency": "pound", "data": [["2019-02-17", "60%"], ["2019-02-16", "70%"], ["2019-02-18", "89%"]]}]
```

I know order by but here where to apply it I don't know. I don't know even if it is possible in query itself.

Also, please note that Rupee & Pound columns are type of **varchar(10)**

DB Fiddle with sample data: https://dbfiddle.uk/_9g-CSjH

Comment: Do you also want to order the inner array by date? Because your current query doesn't guarantee its order either.

Comment: Adding `ORDER BY` to `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` is an open feature request in MySQL, not yet implemented as of version 8.2. You might like to click the "Affects Me" button on this bug report to add your voice to increase its priority: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=94696

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't control the order of the elements in the array using `json_arrayagg()`.

You can use `group_concat()` to manually generate the the ordered json arrays :

```
with cte as (
  select json_array(datetime, rupee) AS obj, rupee as value_currency, 'rupee' as currency
  from currency
  UNION ALL 
  select json_array(datetime, pound), pound, 'pound'
  from currency
),
cte2 as (
  select currency, 
        concat('[',
          group_concat(
            obj
            order by value_currency
          ),
          ']'
        ) obj
  from cte
  group by currency
)
select json_arrayagg(obj)
from (
  select json_object(
                  'currency', currency, 
                  'data', CAST( obj as JSON)
       ) AS obj
  from cte2
) x
```

Result :

```
[{"data": [["2019-02-17", "60%"], ["2019-02-16", "70%"], ["2019-02-18", "89%"]], "currency": "pound"}, {"data": [["2019-02-17", "30%"], ["2019-02-18", "67%"], ["2019-02-16", "80%"]], "currency": "rupee"}]
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/XwApZeX_)

Comment: You say that you can't control the order in `json_arrayagg`, then you use `json_arrayagg` as the last operation??? Your idea is correct but re-arrange the code like so https://dbfiddle.uk/XrhTPwza

Comment: Thanks @Salman A for the remarks, But your query did not produce ordered arrays, and regarding `json_arrayagg`, it is used here to combine both JSON objects representing 'pound' and 'rupee' into a single array, disregarding any specific order.